# url redirection in IIS not working for non existing pages

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, url-routing

I had a page http://domain1.com/blog.aspx.

This page I have deleted and created a website with a new domain just for this page.

like below http://domain2.com/blog.aspx

Then I have added a rule in domain1.com web.config like below

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>

     <rule name="Redirect blog" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain1.com/blog.aspx$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://domain2.com/blog.aspx" redirectType="Permanent" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

But I get 404 error while visiting http://domain1.com/blogpage.aspx

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: The input pattern matches against the part of the URL after the hostname, so remove `domain1.com/` from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues...

{HTTP_HOST} = The host name which is domain1.com, so it will never match your pattern

Also you can do this `pattern="^domain1.com/blog.aspx$"` the `.` need to be escaped.

Now you have to match also on the `request_uri` to capture the page. Below should work. Providing you are re-directing `domain1.com/blogpage.aspx` to `domain2.com/blog.aspx`

```
 <rule name="Redirect blog" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" >
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain1\.com$" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="blogpage\.aspx$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://domain2.com/blog.aspx" redirectType="Permanent" />
  </rule>
</rules>
```